# NotifyPropertyChanged in User Control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, inotifypropertychanged

I am new to WPF, I've a user control in my application which is having a Dependency Property of type List.

In my window, I put that user control and bind this DP to the property of my view's List.

Eventually the property changes, so as the collection but it does not reflect on the user control.

My view implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

DP of my user control does not raise event of property changed.

What could be the possible reason for that?

Code of my dependency property in my user control

```
  public List<ItemsResult> ItemsCollection
    {
        get { return (List<ItemsResult>)GetValue(ItemsCollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsCollectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsCollection", typeof(List<ItemsResult>), typeof(ListingUserControl)
                                    , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, ItemsCollectionChanged));

    private static void ItemsCollectionChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var listingUserControl = (obj as ListingUserControl);
        var itemsResult = (eventArgs.NewValue as List<ItemsResult>);
        if (listingUserControl != null && itemsResult != null)
            listingUserControl.CountLabelVisible = itemsResult.Count > 0;
    }
```

Binding in my view

```
 <my:ListingUserControl ItemsCollection="{Binding Clients}" Title="Client" />
```

Comment: Try using ObservableCollection<T> if you are not using it already. Also, post some code.

Comment: @decyclone As it is a dependency property I don't believe I need observable collection.

Comment: Look at the VS debug output window. If there's any binding error you should be able to see it there.

Comment: Also, you can use a regular `Binding` or `DataTrigger` to set the visibility of your CountLabel instead of doing it in code.

Comment: @HighCore No there is nothing, actually it has been bind for the first time, but later when it change, changes are not being reflected.

Comment: @MSingh also, Dependency Properties are in the UI layer. `ObservableCollection<T>` is a ViewModel-layer thing. Post your viewmodel/model or whatever binding source you're using.

Comment: @MSIngh post the code you're using to modify the binding source.

Comment: @HighCore I've changed the property to ObservableCollection from List and need to change the DP type as well and it works. But there should be some logical explanation why NotifyPropertyChanged is not working and why I have to make my properties of type ObservableCollection.

Comment: Because the WPF Binding mechanism does not recognize changes to lists (such as adding or removing items) by itself. you need to change the whole reference to the List for it to recognize the change.

Comment: @HighCore Yeah, that's correct, I just verify what you said about the "whole reference" thing. If I just create the new list every time when data gets change in that, it works, rather then clear them and reload them. Thanks for being so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, like HighCore wrote, it does not fire any event in case of collectionchange, but only once, when binding changed. What you can do is, check weather the bounded collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged or not. Like:

```
var itemsResult = (eventArgs.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged);
if (itemsResult != null)
{ 
   itemsResult.CollectionChanged += OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
}
```

Then you can monitor collection changes.

Comment: Btw it is not a good idea to use generic type as DP, specially not, when you use your own type. In this case you need to make sure ItemsResult is always accessible by the usercontrol where your control is being used. I would recommend to use IList as DP.